# Is there any System.Drawing.Graphics for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, graphics, bitmap

I'm trying to create an **image generator in a Windows Phone 8.1 application**. I want to be able to create an empty bitmap, write some text in it and then add basic content to the bitmap (lines, circles, etc.).

I am using **WritableBitmap** and I can get the pixels as an integer array. I can modify the array "by hand" but drawing a text for example would be very complicated using this *rough method*.

```
WriteableBitmap bmpCreator = new WriteableBitmap(iImgWidthPX, iImgHeightPX);
int[] vPixels = bmpCreator.Pixels;       
// I want to use a drawing layer using vPixels
// Draw text
// Draw lines
// Apply filters
// bmpCreator.SaveJpeg(...);
```

In a Windows Forms application I could have used **[System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx)**. Unfortunately I don't see this available in Windows Phone 8.1?

Basically I'm searching for a "factory" that **takes the pixel array as input and exposes basic image processing functions**.

**So:** Is there anything like System.Drawing.Graphics made for Windows Phone? If not, is there an alternative to my problem?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Check Win2D https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D

Comment: @BrianRasmussen thank you very much for the link. It seems close to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing what you are looking for is [Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.aspx)
You can draw these onto a canvas, add whatever text you want to add as a label and then render the canvas to a WriteableBitmap (although I am not sure of the last part here).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I checked it out but the functionality seems very limited and cannot solve my purpose.

Comment: @VAndrei: please be more specific. It's not like `System.Drawing.Graphics` offers a wide variety of primitives. Just basic geometric shapes and `GraphicsPath`, all of which are very similar to what you can do with the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes` namespace. You should post a simple example of the `Forms` code you would write, so that we can understand what you're doing there that can't be done with the regular XAML features.

Comment: @PeterDuniho as far as I understood, Xaml.Shapes is more focused towards creating controls with custom shapes. If I want to apply for example a gaussian filter on the image I cannot do this. Microsoft/Win2D, proposed by Brian Rasmussen seems a better solution. I'll more into Xaml.Shapes and maybe I find some "hidden" functionality.

Comment: `Shapes` is XAML's rendering model. It is the "retained mode" equivalent to WinForm's "immediate mode" model. You can create controls from shapes, but you can also render them into a bitmap for other graphical purposes. WinForms doesn't have any built-in Gaussian filter either, so I don't understand that part of your comment. You can apply a Gaussian filter to a bitmap just as easily in XAML as in WinForms; i.e. the convenient, slow way, or the fast, less-convenient way, both involving accessing the bitmap explicitly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks. I documented more and this answers my question.