# How to change color of a image in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows application in which I am getting an image (in black color) from server. I download that image and display it in my application.

Is there a way to change the color of this image (to white color) in code because I want to display a white colored image since I have a black background.

Please let me know if additional info is required from my side?

Comment: do you have an image with black background and change it to a white background?

Comment: No. that is not my requirement.

Comment: @Rachel please add an example image of before and after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverting image returns a black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779809/inverting-image-returns-a-black-image)

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned in [Inverting image returns a black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779809/inverting-image-returns-a-black-image) but none of them worked for me

Comment: @Rachel, which graphics library do you currently use? perhaps Win2D can do what you need, as System.Drawing is not an option here... [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26977886/1132334). Are you in control of the server side? if yes, I'd suggest to have the server prepare the inverted version of the picture for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how far you want to go down this rabbit hole.

You could just convert the image to `32bit` and roll your own image processing routine to convert black to white pixels.

The following is an example of how to use `unsafe` keyword and `Pointers` to achieve this fairly efficiently. Add pepper and salt to taste

[-unsafe (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option)

**Disclaimer** there is other ways to do this, however YOLO

```
unsafe private void ConvertImage(string fromPath, string toPath)
{
    using (Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(fromPath))
    {
       using (Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
       {
          var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height);
          using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
          {
             gr.DrawImage(orig, rect);
          }

          // lock the array for direct access
          var bitmapData = clone.LockBits(Bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
          // get the pointer
          var scan0Ptr = (int*)bitmapData.Scan0;
          // get the stride
          var stride = bitmapData.Stride / 4;

          var white = Color.White.ToArgb();
          var black = Color.Black.ToArgb();

          // scan all x
          for (var x = rect.Left; x < rect.Right; x++)
          {
             var pX = scan0Ptr + x;

             // scan all y
             for (var y = rect.Top; y < rect.Bottom; y++)
             {
                if (*(pX + y * stride) == black)
                {
                   *(pX + y * stride) = white;
                }
                else
                {
                   *(pX + y * stride) = black;
                }

             }
          }
          // unlock the bitmap
          clone.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

          clone.Save(toPath);
       }
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Changed to invert the image

Comment: Bitmap and System.Drawing is not supporting in my app